# Can't stop R from reading .csv files as factors even with stringsAsFactors = F?

Tags: r

I have a CSV file that looks like this:

```
t.trend.dates.  sig
2/23/2017   2
2/23/2017   4
2/23/2017   6
2/23/2017   8
2/23/2017   9
2/23/2017   11
2/23/2017   12
2/23/2017   13
2/22/2017   14
2/23/2017   15
2/23/2017   16
2/23/2017   17
2/23/2017   18
2/23/2017   19
2/23/2017   20
2/23/2017   21
2/22/2017   24
```

And I've read it into R using

```
TrendIndices <- read.csv("TrendingSignals.csv", header = TRUE, sep=" ")
```

And this returns

```
   t.trend.dates. X..sig.
1      2017-02-23      ,2
2      2017-02-23      ,4
3      2017-02-23      ,6
4      2017-02-23      ,8
5      2017-02-23      ,9
6      2017-02-23     ,11
7      2017-02-23     ,12
8      2017-02-23     ,13
9      2017-02-22     ,14
10     2017-02-23     ,15
11     2017-02-23     ,16
12     2017-02-23     ,17
13     2017-02-23     ,18
14     2017-02-23     ,19
15     2017-02-23     ,20
16     2017-02-23     ,21
17     2017-02-22     ,24
> str(TrendIndices)
'data.frame':   17 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ t.trend.dates.: Factor w/ 2 levels "2017-02-22","2017-02-23": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 ...
 $ X..sig.       : Factor w/ 17 levels ",11",",12",",13",..: 10 14 15 16 17 1 2 3 4 5 ...
```

I've tried both

```
write.csv(sig.trend, file="TrendingSignals", row.names = False, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
TrendIndices <- read.csv("TrendingSignals.csv", header = TRUE, sep=" ", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

But I keep getting the error "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'False' not found"

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is a typo: `row.names = False` should be `row.names = FALSE`.

Comment: Oh thanks for that. However, it's returning "unused argument (stringsAsFactors = FALSE)"

Comment: The new error is probably for `write.csv` since it does not have a stringsAsFactors argument.

Comment: Try setting the option globally. Before you run your code: `options(stringsAsFactors=F)`.

Comment: Why are you specifying `sep=" "`? You know what CSV stands for, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this:

```
TrendIndices <- read.table("TrendingSignals.csv", sep = "" , header = TRUE
 , stringsAsFactors= FALSE)
```

gives:

```
> TrendIndices
   t.trend.dates. sig
1       2/23/2017   2
2       2/23/2017   4
3       2/23/2017   6
4       2/23/2017   8
5       2/23/2017   9
6       2/23/2017  11
7       2/23/2017  12
8       2/23/2017  13
9       2/22/2017  14
10      2/23/2017  15
11      2/23/2017  16
12      2/23/2017  17
13      2/23/2017  18
14      2/23/2017  19
15      2/23/2017  20
16      2/23/2017  21
17      2/22/2017  24
> str(TrendIndices)
'data.frame':   17 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ t.trend.dates.: chr  "2/23/2017" "2/23/2017" "2/23/2017" "2/23/2017" ...
 $ sig           : int  2 4 6 8 9 11 12 13 14 15 ...
```